# Chat application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I want to open a diff div of specific person on clicking his name (which is given ) and only want chat of two persons...i am not able to understand how to get diff div on clicking his/her name....
Plzzz help if anybody can get my code......`

[Check this design try to analyse what i wanna say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Dur.png)

Comment: Have you any code snippets? If using query as the tag suggests you could use $('.user') and ensure that the divs have a class named after the user however this is conjecture without knowing how the chat area is made.

Comment: wait peter i will send you code soon...

Comment: ya peter you are right but my code is little bit complicated where i am trying to get id from mysql......based on id it will  display of logged in user and his conversation messages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simple example of choice user with code to add test message.
When you click on user "content_holder" div is reset and loaded new chat window for another user. When you click on "Add test message" button message is added to active window. I think this is what you're looking for [Link to example script](http://jsfiddle.net/whjzrfz1/)

HTML:

```
<div id='ATM'>Add test message</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content_holder"></div>
    <div class="user-list">
        <ul>
            <li class="user" user-id='1'>user 1</li>
            <li class="user" user-id='2'>user 2</li>
            <li class="user" user-id='3'>user 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function addMessage(message) {
    $(".conv").append("<div class='message'>"+message+"</div>");
}

function selectUser(userId) {
    $(".content_holder").html("<div class='messages'>conversation with user"+ userId +"<hr><div class='conv'></div></div>")
}

$(".user").click(function(){
    selectUser($(this).attr("user-id"));
});

$("#ATM").click(function(){
    addMessage("testMessage");
});
```

CSS:

```
.content_holder {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
}
.user-list {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#ATM {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```